# Deixar CSS dentro das página HTML atrapalha o SEO ?

Tags: html, css, seo

Acabei fazendo o site de uma vez, e agora ficou pronto porém vai ser bem complexo linkar todos os CSS's. Queria saber deixar todo css ou quase todo dentro do HTML vai atrapalhar meu rankeamento no google.

Comment: O CSS não afeta o SEO, o importante é o código HTML. É assim que os motores de busca vêem seu site e não graficamente como nós humanos.

Comment: Este fato em si, não. O que afeta mais é o conteúdo, a qualidade do HTML e a performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se sabe ao certo qual algorítimo o Google usa para fazer o ranking dos sites, além desse algorítimo ser constantemente alterado. Portanto, não há como afirmar com certeza se isso vai afetar ou não o ranking do seu site. O que pode ser dito é que não é uma boa prática colocar seu CSS no mesmo arquivo do HTML. Podemos citar alguns motivos:

- Dificulta a manutenção do site;
- Deixa o código carregado de informações não relevantes para mecanismos de busca;
- Informações irrelevantes para leitores de tela.

Logo, não há motivos para não colocar o CSS em outro arquivo.

Comment: Agora me levantou uma questão, porque o *Google* usa o CSS na página ?

Comment: Eu realmente não sei responder essa pergunta, mas posso dar alguns chutes. Eles podem usar algum tipo de interpretador que constrói a página, colocando automaticamente o estilo. Ou pode ser por uma questão de velocidade, já que não será necessário fazer uma solicitação http para baixar outro arquivo. Mas se você olhar bem, eles usam folhas de estilo tbm. No mais, nem sabemos se o jeito de construir o estilo da página influencia mesmo, então é tudo muito especulativo.

Comment: É de notar que o CSS é minificado, mas em uma página em PHP basta `include 'style.css';` e pronto.

Answer (score 0):

Dificilmente, pois o que o mecanismo de busca leva em consideração é o conteúdo textual. Todo o resto será filtrado.

Acredito que o *CSS* influencie somente quando ele determina se os elementos estão visíveis na página ou não. Mas mesmo assim, se o *CSS* estiver dentro da página ou em um arquivo externo não influenciará no *SEO*.